# How to change a tcl program's text box background color?

Tags: tcl

1. Are there any themes which successfully recolor the background of text input boxes in a tcl application?
   I'm trying to make a dark theme for my eyes, but none of the themes I've found can do this, and the program has very large text input boxes with glaring white brightness.
2. What is the variable to recolor text input background color from #ffffff to something else?

This image shows what areas I'm talking about
https://i.stack.imgur.com/MzscT.jpg

Comment: See the [manual](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TkCmd/options.htm#M-background).

Answer (score 1):

The [text manual page](http://www.tcl-lang.org/man/tcl/TkCmd/text.htm) lists the available options to change colors, &etc.

The 'awdark' theme, available at [sourceforge: tcl-awthemes](https://sourceforge.net/projects/tcl-awthemes/) has a helper routine that will set the text colors for you:

```
  set theme [ttk::style theme use]
  if { [info commands ::ttk::theme::${theme}::setTextColors] ne {} } {
    ::ttk::theme::${theme}::setTextColors .mytextwidget
  }
```